# Using (*) in Where command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I am Using this command to get a Local User in Administrators group, and it works

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Groupuser -ComputerName $computer |? {$_.groupcomponent -like '*"Administrators"' -and $_.Partcomponent -like '*"User"'}|ft groupcomponent,Partcomponent
```

But now i want to use variable like this 
 $Group="Administrators" 
   $Account="users"

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Groupuser -ComputerName $computer |? {$_.groupcomponent -like *$Group -and $_.Partcomponent -like *$Account}|ft groupcomponent,Partcomponent
```

but i get nothing back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the group name is "Administrators" you do not need to use a wildcard. The asterisk will match one or more characters. For example:

`"Administrator*"` matches Administrator, Administators, "Administrator
   Groups", etc

`"*Administrators"` matches Administrators, "Windows Administrators", etc

`"*Administrator*"` matches Administrators, "Administrator Groups", "Windows Administrators", etc

For the second command you can use a sub-expression to expand the variable.

```
Where-Object { $_.groupcomponent -like "*$($Group)*" }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example:

```
$Group = '"Administrators"'
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Groupuser -ComputerName $computer |? {$_.groupcomponent -like "*$Group"}
```

The same can be adapted for `$_.partcomponent`.